# How to detect internet disconnectivity in c++/QT based installer

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, networking

We are developing win-mac file sync installer which is quite similar to Dropbox. The installer is built with c++ and QT. We had a use case, where if the internet is disconnected(plugged out network cable (or) not connected to any wifi) so basically no access to web, During this case we need to make the installer into offline.

I tried few approaches like polling continuously to our web servers. If we are not able to reach then we detect as internet dis-connectivity. Due to some reasons we wanted to have clean native implementation which will look for machines network connectivity.

I even tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965303%28VS.85%29.aspx for windows but this is failing in wifi cases even though we don't connect to wifi this example is saying "Network connected".

Can anyone suggest other alternatives. Platform specific solutions also invited.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at [`INetworkManager::GetConnectivity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and check for  `NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_INTERNET` or `NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_INTERNET` in the response.

Comment: However i have one doubt, is it same as INetworkListManager::get_IsConnectedToInternet work because this is even more straightforward to check internet connectivity. Any suggestions for MAC OSX ?